# Will a "yum install django" over write an existing django version

Tags: django, linux, centos, yum, vagrant

I want to update the django on my vagrant box (and have no need or desire to use virtualenv)

will a simple `yum install django` suffice?

Comment: I am not sure whether this applies to your installation, but this states to remove the old version first. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs#remove-any-old-versions-of-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont u use pip to install python packages?

if you dont have pip in your vagrant machine you can just add this line to your recipes file:

```
require_recipe "python::pip"
```

After having pip you can just run

```
pip install Django
```

To get the latest version or you can also specify a version:

```
pip install Django==1.3.1
```

Just one more think, I have a django_blank project in github using django and vagrant ! if you need some recipe fell free to get it from there:
https://github.com/arthurnn/django_blank/blob/master/cookbooks/vagrant_main/recipes/default.rb

Comment: that worked perfectly - thanks - was typing "pip install django --upgrade" will take a look at you Git.